# user input of array in node.js through command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, input

I am writing code for sudoku solver. I am a beginner in javascript. How to take input of array from the user through the node.js. I have to take input like below in node.js using the command line.

```html
0 0 0 2 6 0 7 0 1
6 8 0 0 7 0 0 9 0
1 9 0 0 0 4 5 0 0
8 2 0 1 0 0 0 4 0
0 0 4 6 0 2 9 0 0
0 5 0 0 0 3 0 2 8
0 0 9 3 0 0 0 7 4
0 4 0 0 5 0 0 3 6
7 0 3 0 1 8 0 0 0
```

Comment: Please share the work you have tried to date and problems you have faced.

Answer (score 0):

You can read input line by line like this:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
var matrix = [];
var nbr = 0;

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    matrix.push(line.split(' '));
    nbr++;

    // number of lines to read
    if (nbr > 5)
        rl.close();
});

console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: check the modified answer